# How to show up the intance id in grafana?

Tags: linux, grafana, influxdb, collectd

I need to monitor the system metrics...I am using **collectd influxdb and grafana**

Collectd - To collect all the system metric
InfluxdB - Is used as a database to store the system metric
Grafana - Fetches the values from the influxdb and used for visualization

So...In my grafana dashboard as of now am able to see my CPU and RAM usage
But i want to see the instance name in my grafana dashboard...How can i show up my instnace name...What should i do...

Below is my grafana dashboard...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYorl.png)

Where should i change my configuration to show up my instance name in grafana dashboard.
Please help me...

Comment: U can just modify the legend to dsiplay the name of yours instances

Comment: How to do that?How to modify the legend name ?